# Android Geo-fence not working properly

Tags: android, geolocation, geofencing, android-geofence, android-gps

I am using geofence api for proximity but it is not working properly. some times it gives in range and out range at the same location.

i am also using GPS library to improve accuracy of geofence inrange-outrange but still it is not working properly. i am using below code for geofence :

**I am using 300 meters radius for considering inrange-outrange (enter-exit)**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.geofencedemo">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CheckPermission"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/DialogActivity" />

    <receiver
        android:name="services.GeofenceTransitionsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.geofencedemo.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE" />
            <category android:name="com.geofencedemo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="services.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java (for registering geofence)**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 300;//Meter(s)
private final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS =    Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE;
private int GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER = 1;
private int GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT = 2;
private List<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
private String geofenceID = "testGeofence";
private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences("ISSKEYGEOFENCE-prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Button btnSetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setlocation);
    btnSetLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (!isGPSEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enable Location service to allow set location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){
                Log.d("myTag", "check marshmallow permission...");
                Intent permissionIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CheckPermission.class);
                startActivityForResult(permissionIntent, 1111);
            } else {
                intGoogleAPI();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1111:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                intGoogleAPI();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void intGoogleAPI() {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(3000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>(1);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(final Bundle bundle) {
            if (isServiceConnected()) {
                Log.d("myTag", "request for update current location");
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, MainActivity.this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(final int cause) {}
    }).addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(final ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}
    }).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private boolean isServiceConnected() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.this);
    return ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location mLastLocation) {
    if (isServiceConnected()) {
        Log.d("myTag", "request removed location update");
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
    try {
        addLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public void addLocation(final double latitude, final double longitude) {
    Log.v("myTag", "set lcation lat: " + latitude);
    Log.v("myTag", "set lcation lag: " + longitude);
    mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder().setRequestId(geofenceID).setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT).setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS).setExpirationDuration(GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS).build());
    final List<String> GEO_FENCE_ID_LIST = new ArrayList<String>();
    GEO_FENCE_ID_LIST.add(geofenceID);
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, GEO_FENCE_ID_LIST).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    // successfully removed geofence...
                    Log.d("myTag", "removed old geofence successfully ");
                } else {
                    Log.d("myTag", "Not removed old geofence");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    // successfully Added geofence...
                    Log.d("myTag", "New geofence successfully added");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully added geofence", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isinrange", false);
                    editor.putString("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
                    editor.putString("log", String.valueOf(longitude));
                    editor.apply();
                }
                try {
                    if (isServiceConnected()) {
                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, MainActivity.this);
                    }
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        });
    }
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.geofencedemo.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
}
```

**GeofenceTransitionsIntentService (Trigger inrange,outrange by geofence)**

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
    super("GeofenceTransitionsIntentService");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("ISSKEYGEOFENCE-prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private boolean isLocationFetched = false;
private String geofenceTransitionIds;
private boolean isInRange = false;
private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        int geofenceTransitionType = intent.getIntExtra("TransitionType", 4);
        geofenceTransitionIds = intent.getStringExtra("TransitionId");

        /*final String lat = intent.getStringExtra("TransitionId_lat");
        final String log = intent.getStringExtra("TransitionId_log");*/

        if (geofenceTransitionIds != null && geofenceTransitionIds.length() > 0) {
            switch (geofenceTransitionType) {
                case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                    geofenceTransitionIds(geofenceTransitionIds, true);
                    //new IntGoogleApiClient(appStorage, null, true).Intialize();
                    //processIn(geofenceTransitionIds, lat, log);
                    break;
                case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                    geofenceTransitionIds(geofenceTransitionIds, false);
                    //new IntGoogleApiClient(appStorage, null, true).Intialize();
                    //processOut(geofenceTransitionIds, lat, log);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void geofenceTransitionIds (String geofenceTransitionIds, boolean isEnteCall) {
    if (geofenceTransitionIds != null && geofenceTransitionIds.length() > 0) {
        isInRange = isEnteCall;
        intGoogleAPI();
    }
}

private void intGoogleAPI() {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(3000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.this).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(final Bundle bundle) {
            if (isServiceConnected()) {
                // please consider here location permission is already allowed...
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(final int cause) {}
    }).addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(final ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}
    }).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private boolean isServiceConnected() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.this);
    return ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location passedLocation) {
    if (passedLocation != null && !isLocationFetched) {
        if (isServiceConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.this);
        }
        isLocationFetched = true;
        try {
            if (geofenceTransitionIds != null && geofenceTransitionIds.length() > 0) {
                if (isInRange) {
                    processIn(geofenceTransitionIds, String.valueOf(passedLocation.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(passedLocation.getLongitude()));
                } else {
                    processOut(geofenceTransitionIds, String.valueOf(passedLocation.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(passedLocation.getLongitude()));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        disconnectGoogleClient();
    }
}

private void disconnectGoogleClient() {
    try {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            if (isServiceConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.this);
            }
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

private void processIn(String passedIds, String lat, String log) {
    if (passedIds != null) {
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(passedIds.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

        for (String deviceName : items) {
            if (deviceName != null) {
                boolean isOutRange = preferences.getBoolean("isinrange", false);
                if (mappingRadius(true, deviceName, lat, log) && isOutRange) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isinrange", false);
                    editor.apply();
                    sendNotification(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.this, "In range come!", Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void processOut(String passedIds, String lat, String log) {
    if (passedIds != null) {
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(passedIds.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        for (String deviceName : items) {
            if (deviceName != null) {
                boolean isInRange = preferences.getBoolean("isinrange", false);
                if (mappingRadius(false, deviceName, lat, log) && !isInRange) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isinrange", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    sendNotification(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.this, "Out range come!", Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean mappingRadius(boolean isInRange, String deviceName, String currentLat, String currentLog) {
    final float cLat = Float.parseFloat(currentLat);
    final float cLog = Float.parseFloat(currentLog);
    Log.d("myTag", "GeofenceTransitionsReceiver lat " + cLat);
    Log.d("myTag", "GeofenceTransitionsReceiver log " + cLog);

    float appLat;
    float appLog;
    appLat = Float.parseFloat(preferences.getString("lat", "0.0"));
    appLog = Float.parseFloat(preferences.getString("log", "0.0"));
    Log.d("myTag", "GeofenceTransitionsReceiver app lat " + appLat);
    Log.d("myTag", "GeofenceTransitionsReceiver app log " + appLog);

    Location current_latlog = new Location("crntlocation");
    current_latlog.setLatitude(appLat);
    current_latlog.setLongitude(appLog);

    Location new_latlog = new Location("newlocation");
    new_latlog.setLatitude(cLat);
    new_latlog.setLongitude(cLog);

    final double distance = current_latlog.distanceTo(new_latlog);
    Log.v("myTag", "GeofenceTransitionsReceiver calculation distance is: " + distance);
    //if (distance < 2000) {
        if (isInRange) {
            if (distance <= 300) { // with in 300 Meters consider as in range...
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (distance >= 300) { // more than 300 Meters consider as out range...
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    /*} else {
        return false;
    }*/
}

private void sendNotification(final Context context, String notificationMessage, int color) {
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent());
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)).setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)).setTicker(notificationMessage).setContentText(notificationMessage).setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent).setColor(color).setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 }).setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), builder.build());
}
}
```

**GeofenceTransitionsReceiver (handling/calculate distance after geofence trigger)**

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorString(context, geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.d("myTag", "GeofenceTransitionsReceiver error " +errorMessage);
        // sendNotification(context, errorMessage, Color.RED);
        return;
    }
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
    Log.d("myTag", "GeofenceTransitionsReceiver " + geofenceTransition);

    // for testing....
    //sendNotification(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.geofence_transition_type, geofenceTransition), Color.RED);

    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
        String geofenceTransitionIds = getGeofenceTransitionIds(triggeringGeofences);
        Location triggeringLocation = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("TransitionType", geofenceTransition);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("TransitionId", geofenceTransitionIds);

        serviceIntent.putExtra("TransitionId_lat", String.valueOf(triggeringLocation.getLatitude()));
        serviceIntent.putExtra("TransitionId_log", String.valueOf(triggeringLocation.getLongitude()));

        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    } else {
        // sendNotification(context,
        // context.getResources().getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
        // geofenceTransition), Color.RED);
    }
}

private String getErrorString(final Context context, int errorCode) {
    Resources mResources = context.getResources();
    switch (errorCode) {
    case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
        return "Geofence service is not available now";
    case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
        return "Your app has registered too many geofences";
    case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
        return "You have provided too many PendingIntents to the addGeofences() call";
    default:
        return "Unknown error: the Geofence service is not available now";
    }
}

private String getGeofenceTransitionIds(List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
    List<String> triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
        triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
    }
    return TextUtils.join(",", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);
}
}
```

Is there anything else we can do to improve accuracy and overcome the problem of inrange outrange at the same location ?

Comment: What does not work properly? For points on the radious or where? And why you dropped so much code?

Comment: @greenapps It triggers enter and exit event even phone is at same place. i posted code so one can identify if i have done anything wrong in code. i have used 300 meter radius for enter and exit event but it is not giving accurate result.

Comment: It matters a lot if the phone does not move as then gps chips can not determine position precise so values dwell around the actual position. So you should check which lat lon values are used that cause the trigger before you accuse the geo fence detection.

Comment: i am using library (google-play-services) for current lat & long once Geofence trigger.

Comment: That is no answer to the question. Supply a lat,lon value where it goes wrong.

Comment: When i registered Geofence with 300m radius, it gives multiple Enter/Exit event at same location.

Comment: My god you are only repeating yourself. At which location? Please give an example where the location is for instance at ten meter from center and the geo fence tells you that you are out. Exact figures i was askingl Exact lat,!on of center. Exact lat,lon of location.

Comment: i have registered Geofence using 23.016573, 72.567154 (lat/Long) with 300m radius and Geofence trigger (exit) with 23.016745, 72.56381 (lat/long) at same location.

Comment: Well do let me check that from head at which distance that would be from center? You could take same more effort and do the calculations. Show us what goes wrong.

Comment: In case your EXIT event is not fired when registering geo-fences: I'm currently also having issues with .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT). It looks like only INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER is working properly. But EXIT as initial trigger is never fired in my app.

Comment: Found any solution on EXIT?

Comment: @amin geofence working?

Comment: Yes, It is perfectly working..